# Convert "2020-10-31T00:00:00Z" String Date to long

Tags: java, simpledateformat, epoch

I am having Input Date as ***"2020-10-31T00:00:00Z"***. i want to parse this Date to get Long milliseconds.
**Note: Converted milliseconds should be in Sydney Time (ie GMT+11).**

FYI,

```
public static long RegoExpiryDateFormatter(String regoExpiryDate)
    {
        long epoch = 0;

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+11"));
        Date date;
        try {
            date = df.parse(regoExpiryDate);
            epoch = date.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception is:" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Converted regoExpiryDate Timestamp*************** " + epoch);
        return epoch;
    }
```

**Output:**  **1604062800000** which gives Date as **30/10/2019** by using [Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/), but in input i'm passing 31st as Date.
Can anyone please clarify this?

Comment: What do you mean by milliseconds should be in Sydney time? A number of milliseconds doesn't and can't have a timezone.

Comment: And you're almost certainly wanting `Instant.parse` and some means of converting to a `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Hi @Sweeper,
Thanks for your information. I need to send Converted epoch to Salesforce which will accept only the long value , Not Date format. that's why i am converting Date into epoch after setting timezone. Please let me know if i did anything wrong.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. In this case just use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: It’s a lot easier than you think: `Instant.parse("2020-10-31T00:00:00Z").toEpochMilli()` yields the correct 1604102400000 (@Sweeper is correct that the number is independent of time zones).

Comment: Hi @OleV.V.
I have got solution by using Instant.parse(regoDate).toEpochMilli() , really thank you so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By doing `df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+11"));`, you are asking the date formatter to interpret your string in the GMT+11 time zone. However, your string shouldn't be interpreted in that timezone. See that `Z` in the string? That stands for the GMT time zone, so you should have done this instead:

```
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

In fact, your string is in the ISO 8601 format for an `Instant` (or a "point in time", if you prefer). Therefore, you could just parse it with `Instant.parse`, and get the number of milliseconds with `toEpochMilli`:

```
System.out.println(Instant.parse("2020-10-31T00:00:00Z").toEpochMilli());
// prints 1604102400000
```

**Warning:** you shouldn't really use `SimpleDateFormat` anymore if the Java 8 APIs (i.e. `Instant` and such) are available. Even if they are not, you should use [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org) or something like that.

Comment: Sweeper, if you will allow me, I have seen many answers from you that were better than this one. IMHO the two important things we should help this questioner with are (1) not hardcoding `Z` as a literal in the format pattern string (2) getting rid of `SimpleDateFormat`. Feel free to copy my suggestion from the comment under the question into your answer if you like.

Comment: @OleV.V. See the edit. Is it better now? Tbh, I don't really know how you can not hardcode `Z`, but still use `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: No matter if using the modern `DateTimeFormatter` or the outdated `SimpleDateFormat` uppercase letter `X` will match `Z` as offset (since Java 7 in case of `SimpleDateFormat`). Thanks for improving.